# PHP json_encode() and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, debugging

my case :

I have table in db from which i pull data, then i am converting it using

`json_encode()`

This is the actual code :

```
$result = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($id);

$images = ($this->model_catalog_product->getProductImages($id));

foreach ($images as $key => $value) 
// Here i am looping the data so i can filter useless data i need only the photo //location which is the actual 
{
  $result['photos'.$key] = $value['image'];
}

var_dump($result)

echo json_encode($result)
```

and this is the output... Everything seems to be OK but...

```
array (size=41)
  'product_id' => string '51' (length=2)
  'model' => string 'SAK' (length=3)
  'sku' => string '' (length=0)
  'upc' => string '' (length=0)
  'ean' => string '' (length=0)
  'jan' => string '' (length=0)
  'isbn' => string '' (length=0)
  'mpn' => string '' (length=0)
  'location' => string '' (length=0)
  'quantity' => string '1' (length=1)
  'stock_status_id' => string '6' (length=1)
  'image' => string 'catalog/fk_gewindefahrwerk_slx_2xf_2xg_fkxkkvw68_02.jpg' (length=55)
  'manufacturer_id' => string '0' (length=1)
  'shipping' => string '1' (length=1)
  'price' => string '400.0000' (length=8)
  'points' => string '0' (length=1)
  'tax_class_id' => string '0' (length=1)
  'date_available' => string '2015-07-08' (length=10)
  'weight' => string '0.00000000' (length=10)
  'weight_class_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'length' => string '0.00000000' (length=10)
  'width' => string '0.00000000' (length=10)
  'height' => string '0.00000000' (length=10)
  'length_class_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'subtract' => string '1' (length=1)
  'minimum' => string '1' (length=1)
  'sort_order' => string '1' (length=1)
  'status' => string '1' (length=1)
  'viewed' => string '6' (length=1)
  'date_added' => string '2015-07-08 16:43:29' (length=19)
  'date_modified' => string '2015-07-22 21:32:57' (length=19)
  'language_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'Спортно Окачване &quot;KONI&quot;' (length=48)
  'description' => string '&lt;p&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/p&gt;' (length=29)
  'tag' => string '' (length=0)
  'meta_title' => string 'Спортно окачване KONI BMW' (length=40)
  'meta_description' => string '' (length=0)
  'meta_keyword' => string '' (length=0)
  'keyword' => null
  'photos0' => string 'catalog/fk_gewindefahrwerk_slx_2xf_2xg_fkxkkvw68_02.jpg' (length=55)
  'photos1' => string 'catalog/_goods.jpg' (length=18)
{ "product_id": "51", "model": "SAK", "sku": "", "upc": "", "ean": "", "jan": "", "isbn": "", "mpn": "", "location": "", "quantity": "1", "stock_status_id": "6", "image": "catalog/fk_gewindefahrwerk_slx_2xf_2xg_fkxkkvw68_02.jpg", "manufacturer_id": "0", "shipping": "1", "price": "400.0000", "points": "0", "tax_class_id": "0", "date_available": "2015-07-08", "weight": "0.00000000", "weight_class_id": "1", "length": "0.00000000", "width": "0.00000000", "height": "0.00000000", "length_class_id": "1", "subtract": "1", "minimum": "1", "sort_order": "1", "status": "1", "viewed": "6", "date_added": "2015-07-08 16:43:29", "date_modified": "2015-07-22 21:32:57", "language_id": "1", "name": "Спортно Окачване "KONI"", "description": "<p><br></p>", "tag": "", "meta_title": "Спортно окачване KONI BMW", "meta_description": "", "meta_keyword": "", "keyword": null, "photos0": "catalog/fk_gewindefahrwerk_slx_2xf_2xg_fkxkkvw68_02.jpg", "photos1": "catalog/_goods.jpg" }
```

So here everything seems to be ok the data is encoded but this is my var_dump in chrome javascript console :

```
date_added: "2015-07-08 16:30:49"
date_available: "2015-07-08"
date_modified: "2015-07-08 16:37:14"
description: "&lt;p&gt;ОПИСАНИЕ&lt;/p&gt;"
ean: ""
height: "0.00000000"
image: ""
isbn: ""
jan: ""
keyword: null
language_id: "1"
length: "0.00000000"
length_class_id: "1"
location: ""
manufacturer_id: "0"
meta_description: ""
meta_keyword: ""
meta_title: "Макферсън BRAND"
minimum: "1"
model: "AKS130"
mpn: ""
name: "Макферсън"
points: "0"
price: "100.0000"
product_id: "50"
quantity: "1"
shipping: "1"
sku: ""
sort_order: "1"
status: "1"
stock_status_id: "6"
subtract: "1"
tag: ""
tax_class_id: "0"
upc: ""
viewed: "3"
weight: "0.00000000"
weight_class_id: "1"
width: "0.00000000"
__proto__: Object
```

The photos are missing everytime. I tried as object but the result is the same. I am developing for 3 years but i have never seen such problem before. Please ppl if u have any clues with this one i will be very grateful. Thanks in advance

divanche_pras

Comment: Your JSON and Chrome's output is totally different (product id 51 vs 50). Are you sure you are looking at the right thing?

Comment: Thanks mate... The actual problem is that I ran out of energy drinks. It's very very stupid from my side... Anyway can you post it as answer so I can accept it, and thank you once again :)

Answer (score -1):

PHP's `json_encode`, by default, escapes slashes

Try overriding this by doing `json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)`